# How to copy the hard-disk (>1 partitions, bootloader, & MBR/GPT included) towards smaller hard-disk?

Tags: windows, mbr, clone, hard-drive-recovery, windows-backup

After a full Windows factory settings reset, I have a laptop with multiple partitions and a freshly installed Windows 8 on an 500GB hard-disk. I need to make a fully recoverable hard-disk image/copy/clone of all partitions, tables and sectors on a smaller hard-disk.

Since only about 50GB (10%) are used I would prefer to make a "bundled image" of all partitions including MBR/GPT, etc. on an smaller hard-disk. The scope: **be able to quickly recover the precise actual system setup state** -- including the fresh Windows installation (with all updates, settings, and software installations I've now made), recovery and service partitions, boot-loader, partition-table, etc.. In between I want to format the whole disk and use the laptop as an Debian Linux machine without any Windows options/partitions.

Since I'm about 1y in Linux, I'm neither freak nor noob. So feel free to provide the solutions you find the best and most reliable(!).

(After searching a bit for a good solutions, asked me how it would be if I minimize the size of the Windows partition -- let's say 50GB -- and let the space remaining unallocated. So the size of the allocated partitions would be about 60GB. Then cloning _all_the_allocated_partitions_ with something like Clonezilla or `dd`. I would prefer to use an Live Debian 8 (Jessie) CD for the operation. Could this work?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure software recommendations are *off-topic* here. Try at [SR.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Personally I would recommend Macrium Reflect (using Re-Deploy to restore an image to even different hardware)

Comment: @GiantTree: Thank you for your input. Will wait a bit for more proposals and then decide about Macrium. However, Software Recommendations is really nice -- did not know about it. Thanks :)

Comment: Just use whatever Clone/Backup program you have available. You'd be able to easily do it on the same machine. If you really want to go with Linux you could try `dd` and gzip it afterwards to see if that helps.

Comment: @Seth Thank you :) How could I precisely set (limit) the `if=` size of multiple partitions, bootloader, & MBR. AFAIK `dd` is taking the whole disk. I'm not really aware how `dd` works -- used it only on, relatively small, USB-install-keys --, what output file format does `dd` have?